# ntopng access point and ips

Tags: networking, wireless-access-point

i have an ubuntu server and i just have installed ntopng on it for control all the network traffic on my server.

I noticed that ntopng sorts the hosts by access point (with the MAC address) but as i understand an access point is a router

Then i'm a bit confuse because when i check my ip, i have an access point associate and that access point has a lot of other IPs that obviously are not connected to my router.

When i go to my ip info i see that access point and when i click on it it shows me all the hosts related to that access point (image)
What i am misunderstanding?

[Where do i access to the acces point info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLs4x.png)

[What i see in ntopng](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vw7ve.png)

Comment: Could you show the actual output from ntopng? (And is the server actually monitoring traffic _of_ a wireless network, or is ntopng just using the terms?) I'm not sure if the answer I've written actually applies to this case.

Comment: You can check the edit, i added an imagem thank you

Comment: Why do you call it an "access point"? It's just a MAC address.

Comment: Check the new image i added it, you can see the field named "(Router/AccessPoint) MAC Address" that is the reason i named it AccessPoint is it wrong?

Comment: The server, has multiple databases and web-apps and i wanted monitor the network traffic to and from my server with ntopng

Comment: MAC addresses are point to point addresses. The addresses that you're seeing are the next hop MAC addresses to reach those IPs. Access point or Router isn't necessarily wrong but depending on your network topology it might not be correct either.

Comment: What do you mean by "the next hop MAC addresses to reach those IPs"? you mean that all those ips have done requests from the same device (not necessary an access point)?

Comment: Yes – the router. (Actually the complete opposite of an access point.)

Answer (score 0):

This table doesn't show anything about access points, quite the opposite. (Access points are Ethernet bridges, so packets sent through one *do no* inherit the AP's MAC address.)

However, packets sent through a router *do* use the router's own MAC address – the router will "rebuild" the packets and will not preserve the original MAC header. Similarly, when you send packets to remote hosts (any random host on the Internet), you do so by specifying that they should be sent to the router's MAC, not the destination host's MAC.

In other words, the packets your computer sends look like this:

```
Ethernet header:
    Source MAC: <Your computer's MAC>
    Destination MAC: <The router/gateway's MAC>
IPv4 header:
    Source IP: <Your computer's IP>
    Destination IP: <The website's IP>
```

And packets you receive from the router are the opposite – they have the website's IP address as the IP source, but they always have the *router's* MAC address as the Ethernet source.

As a result, *every single remote host* that you communicate with will appear as having the router's MAC address. So the table you're seeing is completely useless, but also completely normal.